# How to make angular animation work with async pipe?

Tags: angular

Can anyone tell me why my animation stopped playing after changing my code to use async pipe in the HTML template. Previously I was loading my data array this way and the [@ScaleUp] animation was playing fine:

```
    <div  *ngIf ="!loading" class="content"  [@scaleUp]="filteredArr.length"> 
    <div  fxLayout= "row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxLayoutAlign.md="center" fxLayoutGap="20px grid">
        <div (click)="onSelect(user)" fxLayoutAlign="center center"  fxFlex.xl="15%" fxFlex.lg="20%" fxFlex.md="25%" fxFlex.xs="50%" *ngFor="let user of filteredArr">
          <app-user-card  [user] = "user" class="user-card"></app-user-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I am using this code to load and filter my data and the animation stopped playing. I suppose I need to change something, probably add another pipe for the animation, but I don't know. Can someone tell me how it is done?

```
<div  *ngIf ="!loading" class="content"  [@scaleUp]="userArr.length"> 
    <div  fxLayout= "row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxLayoutAlign.md="center" fxLayoutGap="20px grid">
        <div (click)="onSelect(user)" fxLayoutAlign="center center"  fxFlex.xl="15%" fxFlex.lg="20%" fxFlex.md="25%" fxFlex.xs="50%"
         *ngFor="let user of userArr | async | formFilter: formData">
          <app-user-card  [user] = "user" class="user-card"></app-user-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure userArr.length exists? it looks like it's an observable now.

Comment: Yep, it is observable now, any suggestions what to do? Should I subscribe to it in a different place and load all the data into a separate array and use it for this purpose, but then it will load all the data again I think? Any other solutions? Probably if I add another custom pipe that only counts the number of the array or something like that, I am really very new to this hole angular stuff.

Comment: It should be possible to wrap the entire structure in an ng-container so you can use the userArr inside it, `<ng-container *ngIf="userArr$ | async as userArr>...`. Then you can remove the async pipe inside the ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

D.Veen is totally right and help me a ton! Thank you so much! This is the changed code that worked as expected:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf = "userArr | async |  formFilter: formData as userArr">
  <div  *ngIf = "!loading" class="content"  [@scaleUp]="userArr.length"> 
    <div  fxLayout= "row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxLayoutAlign.md="center" fxLayoutGap="20px grid">
        <div (click)="onSelect(user)" fxLayoutAlign="center center"  fxFlex.xl="15%" fxFlex.lg="20%" fxFlex.md="25%" fxFlex.xs="50%"
         *ngFor="let user of userArr">
          <app-user-card  [user] = "user" class="user-card"></app-user-card>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```